# Load select millions options dynamically php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, performance

I have created html form with one select dropdown and one is textfield.

```
<select id="single" name="drug_id" class="form-control select2">
<option></option>   
<?php
$all_drugs= "SELECT drug_id, drug_name FROM drugs";
$result = $conn->query($all_drugs);
$number_of_row = $result->num_rows;
if ($number_of_row > 0) {
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $obj->drug_id ; ?>"><?php echo $obj->drug_name ; ?></option>
<?php
}} 
else { echo "No Medicine Found."; }
?>
</select>
```

Its loading the data from database but its taking 2.8m because drugs table has 1 Million data.

Please help me out to load data in fastest way...

Comment: What interface needs 1 million options in a dropdown?

Comment: First, Since you already know that you have above `0` records in the table, There is no need to check if rows number is `> 0`, Secondary, There is nothing you can do to make the query faster since you're performing Full-Scan on the whole table, If you have a `WHERE` you could use `INDEX` on the `columns` after it to make it faster, Unless you will do a pagination with `LIMIT`ation; Best you can do is a `Search Engine` for the Table, With an INDEX on `drug_name` since you will search depending on it.

Comment: You could create an autocomplete component with a limit of results performing the query by ajax

Comment: yup, use an autocomplete lib

Comment: @Toleo - Yes, I removed condition `if ($number_of_row > 0) ` and data loads in 2.1 Min. I am unable to use where condition because I want to show all options to select.

Comment: @jeprubio - Could you please give me some more hint or example so that I can implement ?

Comment: And to add to @Mihai 's comment.. The browser might stail or lag when you have 1 million options in a dropdown

Comment: @Teju just search https://www.google.es/search?q=autocomplete+jquery and you'll find lots of libraries and examples. In my oppinion this is too broad to be a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AJAX based Autocomplete instead of showing 1 million of options in dropdown.

[View this link for Autocomplete example.](https://phppot.com/jquery/bootstrap-autocomplete-with-dynamic-data-load-using-php-ajax/)
To get the Autocomplete result fast set indexing on MySQL column on which you perform WHERE condition to find out result.